# how to unit test UIApplication extension

Tags: ios, swift

Suppose I use [this](https://gist.github.com/houze2311/dcfd2559975974b0e64f319b51d12a18) code that extracts the top most viewController

```
import UIKit

extension UIApplication {
    
    class func topViewController(_ base: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        
        if let navigationController = base as? UINavigationController, navigationController.viewControllers.count > 0 {
            return topViewController(navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        
        if let tabBarController = base as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabBarController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(selected)
            }
        }
        
        if let presentedViewController = base?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(presentedViewController)
        }
        
        return base
    }
    
}
```

How do I facilitate unit testing of this code? I would need to use an instance of `UIApplication.shared`. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If instead this was an extension to UIViewController, you could omit the parameter (`base`) altogether.

The call would then change to

```
let top = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController.topViewController()
```

In order to unit test this, we can simply create a ViewController and perform our tests.